# Android N java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

In my application i use a self signed certificate to connect over https. The application works perfectly fine when the compilesdk is set to < 24, however when the compilesdk is set to 24 my application fails to connect to the server over https and throws the following exception:

```
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.CertificatePinningInterceptor.intercept(CertificatePinningInterceptor.java:20)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:232)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.OkHttpInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpInterceptor.java:145)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:232)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:49)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:  ... 20 more
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:  ... 30 more
```

I followed the steps mentioned here https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html, however my app still fails to connect to the server over https. My network_security_config.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">test.abc.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/ca_norton"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml included the following under the application tag

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.security.net.config"
            android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />
```

ca_norton.crt is also copied into the raw folder. Am i missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to specify a Network Security Config in your manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
           ... >
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html#manifest. The meta-data approach was only present in the early N previews and is no longer supported.

Comment: Yes specifying android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" in the manifest worked well. Thank you.